# Module with Torsion elements over a ring with no zero divisors

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, representation-theory, homological-algebra

I would like an example of the following: a ring $R$ with no zero-divisors and an $R$-module with a [torsion element](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/torsion+module). Clearly if $R$ has zero-divisors then any $R$-module will have a torsion element. What I wonder is if one can have torsion elements even when $R$ has no zero divisors.

Comment: $\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z$ is a torsion $\mathbf Z$-module if $n\ge0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any finite abelian group is a torsion $\mathbb Z$-module. Also, consider any integral domain $R$, and let $a\in R$ be a nonzero, nonunit element. Then the ring $R/(a)$ is a torsion $R$-module.